# Looking for RPAREN correctly (to enable fast parsing)

Tags: regex, parsing, scripting, opcode

What is the best way to look for the RPAREN in a code?
For instance, I have this pseudo-code:

```
if(a && (b || "c)"))
  |     ^---------^| CASE A
  ^----------------^ CASE B
```

For instance, if I consider the first LPAREN, it need match with the last RPAREN (Case B). If I consider the second LPAREN it need match with the last-1 RPAREN (Case A).

Note that there are the string `"C)"` that have a RPAREN, but it need be ignored for the case.

Well... I think about regex, but I guess that it will be very complex (note that need match strings, regex, and another thinks then can include RPAREN or something like that). Then I think about use a manual scan (via code) to detect each part (like a manual regex).

I need that to parse a code that I'm building (own programmation language). And I want to ignore to read some codes to make it faster.

For instance:

```
function a() { return 1; }
function b() { return 2; }
alert(b());
```

On this case, only `b()` need be parsed, because `a()` never is used. So I will scan by starter `{` and ignore (but store) until the real `}`. If the function is used, it'll be parsed.

My doubts:

1. Regex or manual code?
2. It's a good or a bad thing to do? Do ignore the code if it never is used will help to improve de speed of parser?
3. Off-topic: some tips to faster the parser? Maybe a "pre-parsed" file that store the language code with computer code (opcode???)?

Comment: You cannot parse nested structures with regex. Use a lexical analyzer and parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are building your own language, you should really learn about the standard methods of procesing language source code.  (You're welcome to propose clever new ideas, but most such ideas turn out not to be so clever and if you know the standard ones it is often pretty obvious as to why).

You really can't process your code and "match" parentheses with a pure regular expression.  You need some kind of push down automata or counting engine to match nested parantheses (or anything else that might match, e.g., braces,  IF and ENDIF, ...) often called a "parser" in the context of such tasks.

Regarding your 3 questions:

*1) Regex or manual code?*

Learn about/use parser generators instead, for instance [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org).

*2) It's a good or a bad thing to do? Do ignore the code if it never is used will help to improve de speed of parser?*

This is really a "premature" optimization.  Its better to simply get a fast parsing engine.  ANTLR is pretty good; I doubt if you would notice the difference.  If you insist on blazing fast, consider  [LRSTAR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lrstar/) instead; the guy who built this spent the last decade micro-optimizing its generated parsers, and they're extremely fast.

And given that you are trying to implement a programming langauge, I'd suggest you worry about the much bigger issues of actually defining it crisply, building a working parser, and struggling with executing it in a practical way (whether that means interpreting or compiling doesn't matter).  Given your apparant level of understanding the parsing business, I suspect you really aren't ready to do this.   You'd be better off spending some time learning how compilers work in general so you have a reference point.

*3) Off-topic: some tips to faster the parser? Maybe a "pre-parsed" file that store the language code with computer code (opcode???)?*

You can speed up the parser by preprocessing the text and storing it as a set of tokens.  You can also speed it up by storing the result of the previous parse under the assumption it hasn't changed.(Most source files in big systems of code don't change even though they may get recompiled a lot).  You can even store the compiled code in some representation along with the source text to avoid compiling it. [I've considered storing the compiled code for individual functions like this; even when a file is edited, most of the functions in don't change].   These tricks all have troubles: how do you get the programmer and the editors to cooperate by setting all this up?    Its a lot easier to just build a fast parser, and you should start there and worry about the fancy tricks later.

Answer (score 3):

1. Regex cannot match parens - it isn't possible.
   One way to parse a language like this is lex (tokenize) and yacc (parser) - you can find lots of information on the net.
2. Adding optimizations to the parser is unlikely to make it parse faster but can improve the performance of the resulting code.  Good and bad are moral judgements, I don't know what they mean here.
3. Matching patterns in the source and substituting precompiled, optimized code can give you an improved result, but whether it speeds up parsing depends on how often the patterns appear in the code.

Comment: Yeah... I think about that (it's the manual code method). But about the question 2 and 3? You can answer, please? :)